# Java Spring portlet ajax call fmt not displaying messages

Tags: java, spring, jquery, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I am using following code in ajax controller to load html and return using jquery, problem is html output not display fmt:messages instead ?? this JSP works fine when i try without ajax call. any help appreciated.

```
 @Controller("ajaxRequestController")
    @RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
    public class AjaxRequestController implements PortletConfigAware  {

        @ResourceMapping("entitledRequest")
            public void getServiceAutoComplete(@RequestParam("accNum")  String accNum, ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response){
            portletConfig.getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/account_summary.jsp").include(request, response);
        }

@Override
    public void setPortletConfig(PortletConfig portletConfig) {
    this.portletConfig = portletConfig;
    }

}
```

but problem is

Answer (score -1):

Your `view` is not handled by `Spring` properly because of the below line in your code

```
 portletConfig.getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/account_summary.jsp").include(request, response);
```

Try changing it to the below mentioned code. (I guess you have defined the `viewResolver` in the Spring Context file.

```
  @ResourceMapping("entitledRequest")
        public String getServiceAutoComplete(@RequestParam("accNum")  String accNum, ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response){
        //portletConfig.getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/account_summary.jsp").include(request, response);
        return "account_summary";
    }
```